# spi1 on mangopi-r3 (f1c200s)

Tags: embedded-linux, microcontroller, buildroot

I'm working with mangopi-r3 dev board (f1c200s) and for the buildroot package I'm using this repo —> https://github.com/mangopi-sbc/buildroot-mangopi-r.
I want to add spi1 but I don't know how. could someone help?
sorry if this was a silly question I'm a beginner

Thanks in advance

I tried editing the device tree but I have no experience and I didn't know how to configure it.

Comment: You need to add enable the spi1 node in the device tree at `buildroot-mangopi-r/board/widora/mangopi/r3/devicetree/linux` and add at least one slave device.

Answer (score 0):

You mean SPI ?
You could use the `make linux-menuconfig` to get to

- Linux Kernel Configuration
- Enter into -> Device Drivers
- Enable > `SPI Support` In SPI support verify if you need any other
  settings if required.

I have used a buildroot 2019 version here, it should be similar on other versions
[image: linux kernel menuconfig]